# how to make 4-20 mA signal to replace pressure transmitter with adjustment of variable resistor?

Tags: wireless, power-electronics

I want to replace -B1 (Pressure Transmitter in figure and install a circuit of variable resistor control to get 4- 20 mA signal

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE-EE. This is not a design service, you're expected to do quite a lot more than just stating what you need and hoping someone will design something for you. You might want to include a link to the sensor as well and show how the current is measured. At this moment to answer the question, 90% of the design parameters need to be guessed as you did not make them clear.

Comment: Purchase a calibrator.

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.  Please take the tour at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @R Drast's comment, there is a type of instrument that allows you to control current through a 4-20mA loop, usually for test and tuning purposes. This instrument is called a **loop calibrator**. Here's an example that's pretty common http://en-us.fluke.com/products/ma-loop-calibrators/fluke-707-process-calibration-tool.html.

The thing is $700, but unless you need large quantities this is cheaper and faster than going through the circuit design process. Also, I'm sure you can find much cheaper China-Express versions if your work environment (and project) allows you to use them.